# ETW consuming past event

Tags: c#, logging, etw

I'm planning to use ETW because it:

- Forces to structure the logging
- It's low latency
- The capacity of consuming the events on another process

The idea is to consume the ETW events using an external process like Semantic log application block and forward those events to a central location.

My question is. If the ETW consumer  goes down for any reason while the application continues to send events to ETW is there any way to consume past events?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will record the events while your custom `Recorder` is down. ETW doesn't store anything unless you have a `Session` between your `Provider` and your `Recorder`.

The solution I can offer you is to use [WPR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448223.aspx) and your custom `Recorder`.
Save the traces into file... But remember `ETW` can raise 20K events(you'll receive the BCL events...) in 1 non-sec...(keep the file small, and recover from the failure fast...)

**Edit**

In [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729(v=pandp.60).aspx):

> You could still lose log messages in the out-of-process scenario if the server itself fails between the time the application writes the log message and the time the out-of-process host persists the message, or if the out-of-process host application crashes before it persists the message.

So as I said using 2 applications might help...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can try to use an offline ETW session. It will store the binary traces into a file in disk and then your consumer could get the data from that file.

If your consumer is down, the provider could continue to generate traces.